# filter_by usage problem in query building

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm having some trouble in using SQLAlchemy filter_by:

```
for key in query_dict['filter']:
                query = query.filter_by(key=query_dict['filter'][key])
```

apparently, filter_by won't accept the argument because it can't find the column named 'key' <-- literally! in the table

Is there anyway around this? Oh btw, is there a good link to learn about query building and chaining of sqlalchemy? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work just fine:

```
query = query.filter_by(**query_dict['filter'])
```